# Active suspension with BLDC motor

Tags: torque, bldc

I think about using BLDC motors for an active offroad-robotic suspension. I want the robotic platform to be parallel to the ground as much as possible and saw some videos where BLDC motors were used to simulate spring and dampener systems.

[image]

I am now wondering how much power such a motor would consume during idle position (just standing) to evaluate if this would be a suitable approach. As the angular speed in stall position is zero, the motor is not doing any mechanical work. But in the real world, it will still require some power to hold the position.

**How can I roughly estimate this required stall power?**

I currently have the CubeMars [AK80-64 motors](https://store.tmotor.com/goods-1202-AK80-64.html) in mind, which can easily handle the required torque. But they have a fairly high planetary gear ration (1:64), which means that they might not be backdriveable enough.

**Am I right with this thought and should maybe look for a smaller gear ratio and get a quasi direct-drive motor?**